# Why does this 'onClick disable=true; this.form.submit();' work on one button but not another?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This code 'works' - the button is disabled and the form submits. Happy days.

```
    <form action="timestable_update.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Bank Your Score" name="submitbtn" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

This code doesn't work (I'm looking at id="btn" button)... all that happens is that the button disables, but no submit happens...

```
<form method= "post" action="timestable_submit.php">

        <input type="hidden" name=b value=<?php echo $f;?>>
        <input type="hidden" name=c value=<?php echo $s;?>>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" value="<?php echo $d;?>" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn2" value="<?php echo $w1e;?>">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn3"  value="<?php echo $w2e; ?>">
        </form>
```

Any ideas as to why?

This is the code in it's entirety...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--------------timer---------------->
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var interval;
        var minutes = 0;
        var seconds = 05;
        window.onload = function () {
            countdown('secondsleft');
        }

        function countdown(element) {
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                var el = document.getElementById(element);
                if (seconds == 0) {
                     el.innerHTML = "Time is Up!"; 
                    window.location.assign("timestable_timeout.php")
                    if (minutes == 0) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        minutes--;
                        seconds = 60;
                    }
                }
                el.innerHTML = seconds;
                seconds--;
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>

        <!------------------ timer end ------------>
        <style>
            input[type='submit']{
                position: absolute;
                width: 300;
                height: 50;
                color: white;
                background: red;
                 font-size:100%;
            }
        </style>


                </head>
    <body>

        Level: 1<br>Staff, your score so far is: 0      
        <br>Click on the answer to:     2x11    

        <form method= "post" action="timestable_submit.php">

        <input type="hidden" name="b" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="c" value="11">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" value="22" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn2" value="100">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn3"  value="30">
        </form>
        <!------ timer----->
        <h1><div id="secondsleft"></div></h1>


    <script>

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.style.top = 553+ "px";
btn.style.left = 408 + "px";

var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
btn2.style.top = 452+ "px";
btn2.style.left = 290 + "px";

var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
btn3.style.top = 503+ "px";
btn3.style.left = 542 + "px";
        </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the generated html code? Inspect the page and do so, please. You could also check for console errors...

Comment: first of all wrap `value=<?php echo $f;?>` with quotes, and add htmlentities in case the value might contain a quote `value="<?php echo htmlentities($f);?>"`

Comment: as @FirstOne said you need to post the generated html code... , cant really help you otherwise

Comment: @FirstOne - have added code

Comment: I copy-pasted your full generated code and it worked for me **on firefox**. On chrome it's doesn't work (console shows `Uncaught TypeError: this.form.submit is not a function`)

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the `name="submit"` attribute on the second button.  This causes an issue with Chrome, as it overrides the `submit()` function for your form, resulting in the error that FirstOne has observed in his comment:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.form.submit is not a function
```

If you choose a different name (as you did for your first button) then it should work ok.